# There's a proxy error between Reactjs app and Flask framework when I use docker-compose up

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

Whenever I try to run my app locally, everything works fine.
However, if i try to do `docker-compose up` and access the app on chrome, I get the following proxy error:

> Proxy error: Could not proxy request /packageimport from localhost:3000 to http://127.0.0.1:5000/.
>   See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

I also notice that I have prints on the Flask API, but none are being shown. I've tried to see if it's related, but can't quite figure it out.

I have proxy, supposedly, properly set on the package.json at the React app folder:

```
"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
```

This is my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  backend-aptoide-center:
    build: ./backend-aptoide-center
    expose:
      - 5000
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    networks:
      - same_network
    volumes:
      - ./backend-aptoide-center:/urs/src/app
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=development
      - FLASK_APP=api
      - FLASK_DEBUG=1
      - LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
      - LANG=C.UTF-8
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/aptoidePVC
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
      - frontend-aptoide-center
  frontend-aptoide-center:
    build: ./frontend-aptoide-center
    expose:
      - 3000
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    networks:
      - same_network
    volumes:
      - ./frontend-aptoide-center/src:/usr/src/app/src
      - ./frontend-aptoide-center/public:/usr/src/app/public
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - 'mongo:/data/db'
    networks:
      - same_network
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=aptoidePVC
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example

volumes:
  mongo:

networks:
  same_network:
    driver: bridge
```

The Dockerfile for the Flask API:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends python3 python3-pip python3-dev build-essential python3-virtualenv

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/venv
RUN python3 -m virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 $VIRTUAL_ENV
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT [ "flask" ]
CMD [ "run" ]
```

And the Dockerfile for the React app:

```
FROM node:latest

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app

RUN npm install

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In a docker-compose environment, it is best to address services in containers with the container name (which is automatically set as the hostname of the respective containers as well), rather than IP addresses.

In your case, assuming React is in the `frontend-aptoide-center` container, the IP address `127.0.0.1` would refer to itself as a network node and not the underlying host, since from the perspective of each container, the `127.0.0.1` address is its local loopback address.

Therefore, if you changed the React configuration to `"proxy": "http://backend-aptoide-center:5000/"`, it should route to the intended node on the docker-compose network.